# Search pattern in a specific line in bash

Tags: bash, grep

I would like to find pattern in a specific line (no case sensitive). And if I find it make something.
I can’t use grep since find in all file.
What is the best method?

Comment: With `awk 'FNR==64 && /patterrn/{interesting}' file(s)` maybe?

Comment: Please edit according to the [general guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, where `2` is the line that you want to search for `pattern`:

```sh
sed '2!d;/pattern/I!d' input
```

This sed script basically `d`eletes all lines except line 2, as `2!` is *not line 2*; then among all lines that get past that action, which means only line 2 in this case, all those not matching `pattern` are `d`eleted too.

So all that remains, and is printed by sed implicitly, is line 2 only if it matches `pattern`.

Note that the flag `I` for case insensitivity is not POSIX, IIRC. Try it out. If it doesn't work, you can always use `[pP][aA][tT][tT][eE][rR][nN]`.

Also note that this command will return 0 in both the case of matching and not matching. If you need to take action depending on whether the file matched or not, you can do like this

```sh
[[ -n $(sed '2!d;/pattern/I!d' input) ]] && echo matched || echo not matched
```

If the pattern is a variable, then you can include it like this:

```sh
sed '2!d;/'"$variable"'/I!d' input
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry the number line is also a variable. I try this but not works: 
        for i in "${patrones[@]}"
          do


            if [[ -n $(sed "${Line}!d;/'"${i}"'/I!d" $rutaFich/titles) ]]; then
                   PintaLog "Encontrado el patron $i en la linea $Line"
                  exit 0
            else
                 PintaLog "No encontrado el patron $i en linea $Line"
            fi

        done

Comment: @defekas17 , first, I don't understand spanish, or whatever that language is; second, fix the quoting. Yours is wrong: `"${Line}!d;/'"${i}"'/I!d"`. This is right: `"${Line}"'!d;/'"${i}"'/I!d'`.